# Inserir dados dentro de objetos nas colunas em um DataGrid do Material UI

Tags: react, typescript, material-ui

Bom dia!
Como insiro dados em minhas columns fields que estejam dentro de objetos?
Ex:

```
"cliente": {
  "nome": "NOME DO CLIENTE"
},
"entregador": {
  "nome": "NOME DO ENTREGADOR",
  "whatsapp": "77999999999"
}
```

Eu quero colocar os dados nome que está em cliente e nome que está em entregador, mas não sei como acessar o objeto no campo **field**

```
const columns: GridColDef[] = useMemo(() =>
        [
            {
                field: 'nome',
                headerName: 'Nome do cliente',
                width: 180
            },
            { field: 'whatsapp', headerName: 'WhatsApp', width: 180 },
            {
                field: 'status',
                headerName: 'Status da entrega',
                width: 180,
            },
            {
                field: 'qtde',
                headerName: 'Quantidade de entregas',
                hide: mdDown ? true : false,
                width: 180,
                sortable: false,
            },
            {
                field: 'entregador',
                headerName: 'Nome do entregador',
                width: 100,
                disableReorder: true,
                renderCell: (params) => {
                    if (params.value === null) {
                        return (
                            <Box
                                sx={{
                                    display: 'flex',
                                    alignItems: 'center',
                                    justifyContent: 'center',
                                }}
                            >
                                <Typography
                                    variant="body2"
                                    color="text.secondary"
                                >
                                    Indefinido
                                </Typography>
                            </Box>
                        );
                    }
                }
            }
        ], [smDown, mdDown]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Consegui, galera.
Foi só fazer um map no meu array e passar os campos que eu quero em cada fieldName.

```
    const dataRow = deliveries && deliveries.map((delivery) => {
    return {
        id: delivery.id,
        nome: delivery.cliente.nome,
        status: delivery.status,
        qtde: delivery.qtde,
        entregador: delivery.entregador && delivery.entregador.nome,
        whatsapp: delivery.entregador && delivery.entregador.whatsapp,
    };
});
```

No return em informo os mesmos nomes que defini nas field dos `columns`.